# Should I publish as a master’s student?

Tags: publications, journals, publishability

I am a master’s student and have done some original research work which may not be that great.

I have asked my professor who works in that area where can I publish my work or is it at all publishable.
But he seems to be not so concerned about my work nor does he say whether I should publish it or not.
He says I might try it, but he seems more interested with his doctoral students.

- What should I do?
- Should I try to publish it in some journal?
- If yes, how can I choose a journal?
- Are there any journals which publish small works of master’s students?

Comment: Disclaimer: I can not say this is 100% without knowing the people and the research. Comment: Have you considered your professor is just being polite? I think generally most researchers would be happy to publish something if its publishable, regarthless of who/what education level the original author is at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practice of preparing a piece of work for publication is, itself, worth the effort. I suggest that you write up your work as best you can. Once you have a really solid draft, ask your professor, again, for advice on it.

However, you can still submit it to an appropriate venue, independent of the support of your professor, and that experience is also worth having. If you are lacking in any way, the editors and reviewers of the paper will give you additional advice that is independent of what you can get locally. This can help you evaluate a lot of things about both your work and your approach to it.

If you want a career in academia, then publishing early and often is definitely a plus. The review you get helps you improve for the next time.

But make sure you have also done a literature review to avoid embarrassment of submitting something already known. That is another valuable skill, of course. (literature review, not embarrassment).

Comment: I have some questions,i did a literature review and found that no such has been done on  what i have done but i still believe whatever I have done is not of high regard

Comment: Can  u please help me on how to select a journal

Comment: Sorry, not much help for that. The first place to look is for journals that publish things similar to what you have done, perhaps by looking at where the papers in your bibliography were published. Just make it a reputable journal, rather than a predatory one that just wants to charge you money and doesn't care what you write.

Comment: Okay ,will u please say what is a open access journal

Comment: everyone on their website open access,i dont understand what it means

Comment: The web has lots of resources. Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access

Comment: when i submit a paper in an open access journal it does not charge a fee,so when will it charge it?

Comment: You need to explore that with them. But beware of these: https://beallslist.weebly.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes publishing too early can work against you. You don't want to amass a traceable record of inferior publications. You want whatever appears under your name to be of professional quality.

Answer (score 0):

**Talk to your supervisor**. You write that you've already done it, and his response is "try it". In that case, try it. Write up a draft, then show it to him. Especially if his name is going to be on the paper, he should be willing to take a look at the draft.

Everything that happens afterwards - such as which journal to submit to - can be discussed after your supervisor has approved the draft.